# Input resistance of a BJT common-emitter amplifer

Tags: emitter-follower, internal-resistance

What's the input resistance of the circuit below?

[image]

I think it is \$R_{in}=R_B || r_\pi\$, but I am not sure

Comment: So, what's connected to the emitter?

Comment: @jonk Ground or, if you are asking about small-signal model, then \$r_\pi\$

Comment: Okay. I just wanted to be sure. Then I think you might be about right. You may have a little trouble being sure of \$r_\pi\$, though, for any particular BJT. They vary a lot. (Of course, it is more predictable if \$V_\text{CC}\$ is large.)

Comment: It's a Common Emitter configuration ...not an Emitter Follower. The AC input impedance is Rb // (dIb/dVb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are considering the [Giacoletto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_J._Giacoletto) ([hybrid-\$\pi\$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid-pi_model)) small signal model, you should also add the base diffusion (bulk) resistance \$r_x\$, therefore you have
$$
R_{in}=R_B||(r_x+r_\pi)
$$
The base diffusion resistance \$r_x\$ models the real (not incremental) contact and base region silicon resistance and is \$\leq100\Omega\$ in the best BJTs, but it is not easily predictable since it varies between different production batches and it depends on the BJT constrution technology and on its layout: for those reasons it is also not easily measurable. The incremental resistance \$r_\pi\$ has the following known expression
$$
r_\pi=\frac{I_B}{V_T},
$$
where

- \$I_B\$ is the base bias current,
- \$V_T=\frac{k_BT}{q}\$ and \$k_B\$ is the Boltzmann constant, \$T\$ is the absolute temperature and \$q=1.60217662\cdot 10^{19}\mathrm{C}\$ is the elementary charge.

As said above, \$r_x\$ is not usually found on the datasheet (there are however notable exceptions ([MAT03 datasheet, page 2, \$r_{BE}\$ parameter](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAT03.pdf))), but if you know the [h-parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_junction_transistor#h-parameter_model) of the BJT \$T_1\$, (very easily found in the datasheet of every low frequency BJT), then 
$$
R_{in}=R_B||h_{ie}
$$
since  \$h_{ie}=r_x+r_\pi\$.